# Add new column indicating count in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I have a dataframe with some replicated rows

```
item h2 h3  h4
----------------
foo  v1 ... ...
foo  v2 ... ...
foo  v1 ... ...
foo  v2 ... ...
foo  v1 ... ...
foo  v2 ... ...
foo  v1 ... ...
foo  v2 ... ...
bar  v5 ... ...
bar  v6 ... ...
bar  v7 ... ...
bar  v5 ... ...
bar  v6 ... ...
bar  v7 ... ...
```

My goal is to add a column (`new_id`) in this dataframe which indicates an incrementing count of duplicate blocks (block being a set of rows that have the same `item` name) prefixed with the value in the `item` column (if it helps, the replicated blocks will be consecutive)

```
item h2 h3  h4   new_id
-----------------------
foo  v1 ... ...  foo1
foo  v2 ... ...  foo1
foo  v1 ... ...  foo2
foo  v2 ... ...  foo2
foo  v1 ... ...  foo3
foo  v2 ... ...  foo3
foo  v1 ... ...  foo4
foo  v2 ... ...  foo4
bar  v5 ... ...  bar1
bar  v6 ... ...  bar1
bar  v7 ... ...  bar1
bar  v5 ... ...  bar2
bar  v6 ... ...  bar2
bar  v7 ... ...  bar2
```

Suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by both columns `item` and `h2`:

```
df['new_id'] = df['item'] + '_' + df.groupby(['item','h2']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
print (df)
   item  h2   h3   h4 new_id
0   foo  v1  ...  ...  foo_1
1   foo  v2  ...  ...  foo_1
2   foo  v1  ...  ...  foo_2
3   foo  v2  ...  ...  foo_2
4   foo  v1  ...  ...  foo_3
5   foo  v2  ...  ...  foo_3
6   foo  v1  ...  ...  foo_4
7   foo  v2  ...  ...  foo_4
8   bar  v5  ...  ...  bar_1
9   bar  v6  ...  ...  bar_1
10  bar  v7  ...  ...  bar_1
11  bar  v5  ...  ...  bar_2
12  bar  v6  ...  ...  bar_2
13  bar  v7  ...  ...  bar_2
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I just updated my question to clarify the example.. sorry for the confusion. Can you look at it again and update your answer? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.cat()` to concat column `item`  with the cummulative count of each group in `h2`. Obviously the cummulative count begins from zero, offset it by 1

```
df.item.str.cat((df.groupby('h2').cumcount()+1).astype(str),sep='')



  item  h2   h3   h4 new_id
0   foo  v1  ...  ...   foo1
1   foo  v2  ...  ...   foo1
2   foo  v1  ...  ...   foo2
3   foo  v2  ...  ...   foo2
4   foo  v1  ...  ...   foo3
5   foo  v2  ...  ...   foo3
6   foo  v1  ...  ...   foo4
7   foo  v2  ...  ...   foo4
8   bar  v5  ...  ...   bar1
9   bar  v6  ...  ...   bar1
10  bar  v7  ...  ...   bar1
11  bar  v5  ...  ...   bar2
12  bar  v6  ...  ...   bar2
13  bar  v7  ...  ...   bar2
```